# Checking if the table is present in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am designing a feedback page for my college which collects feedback from 60 students 
about their faculty. I also want to hide the details of the student who provides the 
feedback. So the code will be creating table of each students at the run time. I'm stuck at 
this point. I am not able find the logic on how the table is created during run time and 
what will be the table names and how it will differentiate with one another?

Comment: Don't create a bunch of tables at runtime - build a single table which is properly designed to handle the data you're inserting.

Comment: I'm really wondering how you went from _"I need to hide user data from other users"_ to _"I need a table per user"_. Please re-evaluate your design.

Comment: @CodeCaster rather agree with you, but at sql-server schema level a table is a [securable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190401.aspx). But quite hard to use this opportunity in the described case.

Comment: @tschmit007 sure, then the next question becomes _"How to create a SQL user for everyone who fills out my form?"_. It is a useful feature, but indeed not really applicable to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Having one table per student would be really impractical, use 1 table for every student instead with a different studentID per student.

Say you want to have the student's last and surname stored you could use this table structure:

`CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
    surname TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
)`

then to add students you could INSERT them:

`INSERT INTO Students VALUES("mylastname", "mysurname")`

As for how to interact with a MySQL database using C# check the documentation on the MySQLDataClient:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Comment: Each student is providing feedback of 5 lecturers by answering 5 questions for each lecturer. So in what way i can store all the feedback from students into one table?

Comment: Pick up a database design book or course or read about database normalization.